# Fetch Occurrence of alphabet in a string c#

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string which look likes

> E-1,E-2,F-3,F-1,G-1,E-2,F-5

Now i want output in array like

> E, F, G

I only want the name of character once that appears in the string.

My Code Sample is as follows

```
   string str1 = "E-1,E-2,F-3,F-1,G-1,E-2,F-5";
            string[] newtmpSTR = str1.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            Dictionary<string, string> tmpDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach(string str in newtmpSTR){
                string[] tmpCharPart = str.Split('-');
                if(!tmpDict.ContainsKey(tmpCharPart[0])){
                    tmpDict.Add(tmpCharPart[0], "");
                }

            }
```

Is there any easy way to do it in c#, using string function, If yes the how

Comment: Liam Can you tell how

Comment: People who only visit this question to down vote, your feedback is really required

Comment: People are downvoting this because it lacked effort. You have improved it by showing some code, but your original question smelled of *I can't be bothered working this out myself please someone do it for me*. It's likely a good idea to review the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages

Comment: Thanks Liam for the feedback, Will keep this in mind

Comment: Be wary of asking too many poorly recieved questions. You can [recieve a question ban](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). Always think your question though before posting.  FYI, deleting bad questions doesn't alter the chance of you getting a ban. It's better to ask a good question in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string input = "E-1,E-2,F-3,F-1,G-1,E-2,F-5";
string[] splitted = input.Split(new char[] { ',' });
var letters = splitted.Select(s => s.Substring(0, 1)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Maybe you can obtain the same result with a regular expression! :-)